# How to set NetBeans 7 internet connection?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 7. Tried to create a Maven Java project, failed.

In NetBeans

```
mvn.bat -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -Darchetype.interactive=false -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -Dbasedir=F:\\NetBeansProjects -Dpackage=com.mycompany.mavenproject1 -DartifactId=mavenproject1 "-Dmaven.repo.local=C:\\Documents and Settings\\xxx\\.m2" --batch-mode archetype:generate
```

It failed, because

```
Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
```

Then copy that command into DOS, it works.

Looks like NetBeans can't connect to internet. Eclipse on the same machine can connect to remote internet.

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that NetBeans 7 comes bundled with an embedded version of Maven. This means that any proxy settings you may have configured under your downloaded Maven distribution are not used by NetBeans.

You have two options:

- Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Maven > Maven Home -- point NetBeans to your existing Maven download; that is, where you have configrued settings.xml with your proxy settings;
- Edit path/to/nb7/java/maven/conf/settings.xml with your proxy settings.

Answer (score 2):

Well it is not necessarily internet issue

- If you are behind proxies you need to tell maven in settings.xml about proxy
- If that lib ins't available on the maven repos download it from official sitre and install it manually

Comment: my settings.xml should be good, because I can run that command in DOS. it should be related to Netbeans. I realize even Netbeans can't "check for update"

Comment: Can you check it in NB. you might have wrong proxy configured. goto tools > options > proxy

Comment: I am using System Proxy. Should be fine.

Comment: Have you checked `work offline` in maven settings from options in NB ?

Comment: How ? I set Local Repository to my "C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\.m2" is this the reason ? Thansk

Answer (score 0):

**Either**

`Disable antivirus firewall protection for a while.`

**Or**

`Add netbeans in exception list of the firewall.`

In my case Avast firewall had blocked connection and I've disabled it for a while and it worked.

**That's it !!!**